# I want to sort this list in .NET my sample code is below

Tags: .net, linq, sql-order-by

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Period 01 2008, Period 02 2008
        Series s1 = new Series { Text = "Period 01 2008", Value = "1"};
        Series s2 = new Series { Text = "Period 02 2008", Value = "2" };
        Series s3 = new Series { Text = "Period 03 2008", Value = "3" };

        Series s11 = new Series { Text = "Period 01 2009", Value = "1" };
        Series s21 = new Series { Text = "Period 02 2009", Value = "2" };
        Series s31 = new Series { Text = "Period 03 2009", Value = "3" };

        Series s12 = new Series { Text = "Period 01 2010", Value = "1" };
        Series s22 = new Series { Text = "Period 02 2010", Value = "2" };
        Series s32 = new Series { Text = "Period 03 2010", Value = "3" };

        List<Series> series = new List<Series> { s21, s31, s1, s12, s11, s2, s22, s3, s32 };


       // mySeries.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("Period {0} {1}",i.Period, i.Year));
        series.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Text));

        Console.WriteLine("************************");

        series.OrderBy(i => i.Text);

        series.ForEach(i=> Console.WriteLine(i.Text));

    }

}


public class Series
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Basically I want my list to be ordered by the `Text` property of the `Series` class. I have a work-around by splitting the text, but I am looking for any other way - using `IComparer` maybe?

The ordered list should be something like this:

> Period 01 2008, Period 02 2008, Period 03 2008, Period 01 2009,
>   Period 02 2009...

**Update:** the definition of the `Series` class cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following comparer

```
public class SeriesTextComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string[] xparts = x.Split(' ');
        string[] yparts = y.Split(' ');

        if (xparts[2] == yparts[2])
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(xparts[1]) > Convert.ToInt32(yparts[1]))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(Convert.ToInt32(xparts[1]) < Convert.ToInt32(yparts[1]))
            { 
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        { 
        if (Convert.ToInt32(xparts[2]) > Convert.ToInt32(yparts[2]))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(Convert.ToInt32(xparts[2]) < Convert.ToInt32(yparts[2]))
            { 
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And change last two lines in your example as below

```
List<Series> sortedSeries =  series.OrderBy(i => i.Text, new SeriesTextComparer()).ToList();
sortedSeries.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Text));
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you are always going to have month and year numbers in position 2 and 3. Hence no error checks in my code. You can add error checks if you want

Comment: Thanks alot this is what I have been expecting. yes years and period will always will be in that position

Comment: @pavan-josyula if this solves your problem then may be you can accept the asnwer

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ `OrderBy` extension method returns a new sorted sequence, which you aren't doing anything with.
It doesn't modify the original list.

Instead, you can call `List<T>.Sort`, which is an in-place sort that mutates the `List<T>` instance:

```
series.Sort((a, b) => a.Text.CompareTo(b.Text));
```

Comment: yea I see what you mean after chaging that line to this
series = series.OrderBy(i=>i.Text).ToList();
I am geting output like this
Period 02 2009
Period 03 2009
Period 01 2008
Period 01 2010
Period 01 2009
Period 02 2008
Period 02 2010
Period 03 2008
Period 03 2010
************************
Period 01 2008
Period 01 2009
Period 01 2010
Period 02 2008
Period 02 2009
Period 02 2010
Period 03 2008
Period 03 2009
Period 03 2010
Press any key to continue . . .

by I am looking for some thing like this
Period 01 2008
Period 02 2008
Period 03 2008

Comment: You need to write a different comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Update second last line in main method to:

```
series = series.OrderBy(i => i.Text).ToList();
```

Happy coding

Comment: This is how Iam getting 
************************
Period 01 2008
Period 01 2009
Period 01 2010
Period 02 2008
Period 02 2009
Period 02 2010
Period 03 2008
Period 03 2009
Period 03 2010
Press any key to continue . . .
but I am looking for Period 01 2008, Period 02 2008, Period 03 2008,Period 01 2009, Period 02 2009 and so on

Comment: I see what you mean, you need to modify last line like:  series.ForEach(i=> Console.WriteLine(i.Text)+","); isn't it

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `DateTime` property

```
Series s1 = new Series { 
    Text = "Period 01 2008", 
    Value = "1", 
    PeriodStart = new DateTime(2008, 01, 01) 
};
```

and order by it:

```
series.OrderBy(i => i.PeriodStart).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Text));
```

so you don't get all Januaries together.

Also, your sorting won't be affected by any changes to `Text` property, which seams to be for display purposes.

Comment: -1 ForEach is on `List<T>` so it doesn't compile.  Changes to Text likely need to affect sort, and although unstated, the OP cannot change the `Series` class definition.  `ToList` on the `OrderBy` will fix your example.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't do this myself, this works:

```
var sorted = series.OrderBy(s => s.Text.Split(' ')[2].Trim()).ThenBy(s => s.Text.Split(' ')[1].Trim());
```

This demonstrates the type of LINQ needed to do the sorting.  I haven't done so here, but you will need to be more defensive around null/missing string parts.

**Alternatively**

A slightly different way to tackle the problem is to wrap the `Series` class and expose more useful properties (disclaimer, better parsing code required!):

```
class BetterSeries
{
    public int Quarter {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public Series InnerSeries {get;private set;}

    public BetterSeries(Series s)
    {
        string[] parts = s.Text.Split(' ');
        Quarter = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim());
        Year = int.Parse(parts[2].Trim());
        InnerSeries = s;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Period {0} {1}", Quarter, Year);
    }
}
```

This will then let you sort a little more simply:

```
var sorted = series.OrderBy(s => s.Year).ThenBy(s => s.Quarter);
```

It also means you aren't encoding information into the formatted output of the data, you store the data itself and then add code to format the output.

Comment: but the problem is I cant change the class definition. The text always comes in this format "Period 01 YYYY". I need to sort it by  period number and then by year

Comment: -1 - I believe you will have problems with order preservation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Comment: @JakubKonecki Where does that link mention preservation?  I actually tried this code in a console app and it works fine.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth would u please share the output once

Comment: @Adam - he wants the following order: 01 2001, 02 2001, 01 2001, 02 2002. You first order by quarter and in the second call you order by year, which may not preserve the previous sort. I believe you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852.aspx and use `ThenBy`

Comment: @PavanJosyula The output is the same as what you are expecting, but you just commented that you cannot change the series definition.  The only way you are going to get to sort it correctly is if either alphabetical sorting does the trick, or you break the string down into parts.

Comment: Thanks for your time but is there a way with out changing the Series class definition with just using the text property

Comment: @PavanJosyula I have updated my answer showing how to sort on the Text property.  Even if you cannot modify the class itself, you can still  wrap the class in your own class and handle the Text parsing internally.

Comment: @JakubKonecki I've amended my answer to use `ThenBy`.  To be honest, it's not a featured I've actually needed yet lol

Comment: @Adam - That's what I love about SO - you can learn something new even in the areas you thought you knew well ;-)